# How to cut off an image at the edge of the screen?

Tags: css, image, overflow

I have an `<img>` whose source is larger than the screen. So it overlaps the right border of the screen, which makes my page horizontally scrollable. I want the image to be cut off at the right screen edge, so my site is no longer larger than the screen. How can I achieve this?

Here is a screenshot when scrolled all the way to the right:
[image]

Comment: `body {overflow-x: hidden}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using a CSS property called [overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp). This comes into effect whenever a element overlaps with another, and the default is `overflow: visible` which means that the container element will render outside of the element, so that the child element is still visible.

Assuming you don't have a more specific container that would be more appropriate(because this will apply to all elements), you can simply do:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

This will prevent rendering of any child element that is outside of the parent at all.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I'm looking for.